# how to get column name from 1 table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables.

> task table

task_name = primary key

```
+----+-----------+ 
| id | task_name |    
+----+-----------+ 
|  1 | Task 1    |    
|  2 | Task 2    |   
|  3 | Task 3    |    
+----+-----------+
```

> manager table

task_id = foreign key of task_name in task table

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | set_status | task_id |
+----+------------+---------+
```

I need to show the manager table, but instead of task_id  (showing the IDs of the task_name ) I need to show the actual task name, in place of task_id.
And also show set_status pending by defult when initialy task created by user.

required output

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | set_status | task_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | pending    | Task 1  |
|  2 | pending    | Task 2  |
|  3 | pending    | Task 3  |
+----+------------+---------+
```

I have tried a few queries:

```
SELECT t1.task_name, t2.task_id
FROM task t1 
INNER JOIN manager t2
ON t1.id = t2.task_id
```

But I got

```
+-----------+---------+
| task_name | task_id |
+-----------+---------+
| Task1     |       1 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: To get 3 columns, you have to select 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `left join`

```
SELECT t1.task_name, t2.task_id,'pending' as task_status
FROM task t1 
left JOIN manager t2
ON t1.id = t2.task_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but I'm still not able to see task names under task_id column. Can you please provide more details on it.